# How to get Registration data to used in Login Request

Tags: json, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I make Test Plan in Jmeter consist of Registration and Login.

[image: My HTTP Request Login Picture]

First, I run Registration Request and after that I would like to get the results (email & password) that have been verified to used in Login.

I make user defined manager but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On the picture you have attached the regular expression extractor to the login sampler. If your registration request is answering with the response containing email & password add 2 regular expression extractors there (on the registration sampler) and take the email with the first + the password with the second extractor + make sure you fill in the Server Name or IP field in the requests (don't see them on the picture)

Comment: the problem is, the respons of registration is not contain email and password. and are those values retrieved in http response body. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missing one request, it should be like:

1. Obtaining the Request Token and Token Secret using the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret
2. Obtaining the Authorization Token using the Request Token and Secret
3. Exchanging the Authorization Token to the Access Token -  which can be used to access protected resources.

And on each step you need to perform correlation, like extract dynamic parameter from previous response and pass it with the next request, I don't see the relevant post-processors in your test plan so I would suggest using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) for this.

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more details on bypassing OAuth login challenge in your JMeter test.